# How to execute login to web application with multiple users using Nbomber

Tags: multiple-users, nbomber

I want to execute login to an application with multiple users and execute each step according to user
user should be able to login and execute all step. I alerady tried it with Nunit but it is executing only step1 with multiple users and it is not executing remaining steps with user1.